# Ruby on Rails - How to show fields in a table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows

If I have a table named Products, is there anything I can type into the cmd prompt to display the field(column) names contained in Products?

I tried `rails Products.column_names` but that produces an error.

Comment: don't forget that you can always check the `schema.rb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the command line, type in `rails c`, or use the console supported by `better-errors`.

Typing in the table name, will automatically show a list of attributes.

```
Product
```

To return an array of attribute names, type in

```
Product.attribute_names
```

If you want to see if your table has a particular attribute, try

```
Product.attribute_names.include?("price")
```

You can also use

```
Product.method_defined?(:price)
```

or

```
Product.methods.include?(:price)
```

Comment: I was missing "rails c." This is perfect, Thank you

Comment: I like using `#grep` over `#include` when you don't know what you're looking for, so `Product.attribute_names.grep /ric/` will also return `price`, especially for long lists of attributes or methods

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
Product.attribute_names
```

Details is [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/ClassMethods/attribute_names).

Comment: This wouldn't work in the regular command prompt, only in the rails console.

Comment: Thanks. I tried 'rails Product.attribute_names' but it says Product.attribute_names is not recognized

Comment: I typed it while being in the general folder of my app. Should I be typing it elsewhere?

Comment: @SwolleyBible You should open Rails console `rails console` then type `Product.attribute_names` in Rails console and press ENTER.

Comment: @maxd The windows command prompt. Yes, I was missing the rails console. Lol @ pressing enter

Answer (score 0):

Just try `Product` in your rails console. Alternatively you could also try `Product.new` to see the attributes.